# Folding footnotes in VS Code

Tags: footnotes, code-folding, visual-studio-code

Folding sections works well in VS Code, but would someone know whether there is an extension that allows folding footnotes? I typically do this in VS Code:

```
Here is some text.\footnote{
reference text
}
And here the next sentence continues.
```

This results in the footnote being indented and a vertical structuring line being put in front of it.  So, my question is whether there is a VS Code extension that can fold these indented parts (whether it is a `footnote` or `blockquote`).

Comment: Could you tell me what Visual Studio Code extensions you recommend as the TeX editor?

Comment: Next to the obvious LaTeX Workshop and Fold Plus (or Fold Level), Bracket Select is quite helpful. I think the Cobalt2 and Community Material Theme make the most sense for tex code.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found an answer. Because this may help others with the same question later: the Fold Plus extension allows one to switch between 'language folding' and 'indentation folding'.

By default, VS Code folds based on language, which is why the Fold command folds (for instance) all sections. By choosing 'Toggle Indentation/Language Folding' through the Command Palette in VS Code, one can activate folding based on Indentation.

Depending on whether one puts the opening bracket `{` on a new line or not, the folding sign is put either next to that `{` or at the start of the paragraph. See the screenshots below:

[image: Option 1 - Inline code folding LaTeX footnotes in VS Code with Fold Plus]

[image: Option 2 - Inline code folding LaTeX footnotes in VS Code with Fold Plus]

Comment: Btw, you can accept your own answer to the qn.